Excel VBA optimizing PDFs and making them readable
this is my first post, don't be too hard on me.:
I am having trouble with this Excel VBA Code.:
Sub OptimierePDFFürTexterkennung()
    Dim AcrobatApp As Object
    Dim AVDoc As Object
    Dim PDDoc As Object
    Dim OptimParams As Object
    Dim pfad As String
    
    pfad = "--"

    Set AcrobatApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    AcrobatApp.Show 
    
    Set AVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
    If AVDoc.Open(pfad, "") Then
        Set PDDoc = AVDoc.GetPDDoc
        
        
        Set OptimParams = CreateObject("AcroExch.OptParams")   -->  Here is where I am getting the Error              

        With OptimParams
            .AddItem "AllOptions", 3 
            .AddItem "MakeSearchable", True
            .AddItem "RecognizeText", True 
            .AddItem "UseLanguageDictionaries", True
            .AddItem "UseCorrectReadingOrder", True 
            .AddItem "LanguageDetectionMode", 3 
        End With
        
        PDDoc.Save 1, pfad, True, OptimParams
        
        AVDoc.Close True
    Else
        MsgBox "Fehler beim Öffnen der PDF-Datei"
    End If
       
    Set AVDoc = Nothing
    Set PDDoc = Nothing
    Set AcrobatApp = Nothing
End Sub

I got the Error Code 429 "Object Creation failed due to ActiveX Component", searching the web lead me to many Problems throughout the Years, but they were fixed by using the "Set OptimParams = CreateObject("AcroExch.OptParams")" Block which i already used.
I went further and tried to create a String containing all the settings for saving the PDF instead of creating an Object containing the Settings:
I used
OptimSettings = "/S /C /D /N /M"
...
PDDoc.Save 1, DestPath, True, OptimSettings 

That sadly didnt help aswell as i received the Error Code 450 stating that the Amount of Arguments or wrong association of the characteristic.

I think there is a conceptual problem, there are zero other google hits for "AcroExch.OptParams" ...

Are you using the correct object - as Alex K has said, there is nothing out there for AcroExch.OptParams and it doesn't appear anyway in the Adobe documentation  https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/library/interapp/IAC_DevApp_OLE_Support.html
That error message doesn't appear anywhere either - is it "ActiveX Component can't create Object"? If so, there is no OptParams in your AcroExch.exe

CreateObject("AcroExch.OptParams") seems like a GPT hallucination...

@AlexK. Yeah, like Tim said, that might a GPT Hallucination ;)  After some more Hours of looking it up I found out that there is no proper way of executing this task of optimizing the PDF to make it readable with just VBA. I am currently trying to execute a small java script that performs a customized command within the PDF Instance. I will keep you guys updated on how that worked out
